# Can I change the datatype of previously declared variable in C?

Tags: c, string, types, casting, declaration

I have declared a string and using malloc function I allocated the memory... Now I want to change this string into a floating type.

```
char *str;
str=malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
strcpy(str,"123.4");
float i=strtof(str, NULL);
```

Now I don't want to use a new variable 'i'  instead, I want to store it in str  itself. It is required for me to access data from 'str'
1. Is it possible ??
2. If not suggest a better solution or indirect method.
Please answer 1st question clearly.

Comment: Data types in C are static.  Why do you want to do this?  What problem do you think doing this will solve?

Comment: Explain what you're trying to achieve and maybe we can help you

Comment: I am using a 3D array of strings . Its called inventory data structures.  
In that Iam storing floating points as well as character as strings but I want to convert valid strings to float type  and I want to access it from there itself. Is it possible??

Comment: Store both strings and floats. Only use the floats when they are valid.

Comment: Instead of a 3D array of simple strings, you could make a 3D array of a custom data structure that fits your needs, something like storing both strings and floats as @Lundin suggested or even a wrapper to string with a `.toFloat()` method.

Comment: I can't change the original code as it is given by my professor. He used a
3 D matrix and gave the following problem statement. 
Write a function to 
convert between the data types. You know that table houses float data as well in the form of 
strings. Write a function to convert such strings to float values. You need to devise a 
mechanism to only convert the valid fields. Example: the field ‘car’ should not be converted to 
float type.

Comment: @PraveenNaik That statement doesn't seem to say anything about storing the `float` in the same place as the string.  It also doesn't say what to do with the converted values.  Do you just print them or store them elsewhere?  I suspect you don't fully understand what is being asked. Perhaps placing the complete problem description in your question would clarify things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the pointer returned by `malloc()` is sufficiently well aligned to be used as a pointer to any type, you could (but probably shouldn't) use:

```
assert(sizeof(float) <= 10);
void *data = malloc(10);
char *str = data;
strcpy(str, "123.4");
float *vp = data;
*vp = strtof(str, NULL);

…use *vp…

free(data);
```

And now you can use `*vp` for the `float` value.  However, that's ridiculous compared with:

```
char *str = malloc(10);
strcpy(str, "123.4");
float value = strtof(str, NULL);

…use value…

free(str);
```

which is basically your original code — that you decided for unclear reasons was not what you wanted to do.

Comment: Thank You. Even though this doesn't completely solve my problem but I can use it as an indirect method. I wish I could able to explain my problem statement more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it, but it's ugly, unsafe, may not work as expected, and is most definitely *not* recommended.

You can treat the first `sizeof (double)` bytes of the memory pointed to by `str` as a `double`<sup>1</sup>:

```
*(double *)str = strtod( str, NULL );
```

Basically, we're treating `str` as the address of a `double` object and assigning the result of `strtod` to it.  To access that `double` value, you'd need to cast again:

```
printf( "value stored in str = %f\n", *(double *) str );
```

Now, this means we've overwritten the first `sizeof (double)` bytes of the string with the `double` value, so you've lost the original string value.  If you need to preserve the original string value while also treating it as a floating-point value, then you *have* to use separate objects to do so.  C isn't Python or Javascript, and values don't magically change their representation based on context.

---

1. Unless you're really constrained on memory or have a specific reason to use `float`, use `double` instead.  This also means you need to make sure the memory you allocate is *at least* `sizeof (double)` bytes wide.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `union` for that.

```
union mytype {
  char * str;
  float f;
};
```

Comment: I get what you're trying to say.... but this is totally **not** what OP wants.

Comment: What the hell, this is literally one of the best ways of doing it, needs minor changes but yes. OP say "Now I don't want to use a new variable 'i' instead, I want to store it in str itself. It is required for me to access data from str. Is it possible ?? If not suggest a better solution or indirect method."